# AngularJS: add selected dropdown item to dropdown toggle

Tags: angularjs

How can I add the selected item from `dropdown` menu to the button that opens that `dropdown`?

Example: I want to replace 'DIFFERENCES' with text selected from the dropdown menu; if I select 'All' then the text 'DIFFERENCES' should be replaced with 'All'...

```
<div class="filter-requests btn-group">
  <div data-toggle="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
      DIFFERENCES
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Exclusions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Differences</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Variable Differences</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" >Path Differences</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**view.html**

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
  <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
    {{selected || 'Select one'}} <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-click="changeOption('Action')">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-click="changeOption('Another action')">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-click="changeOption('Something else here')">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#" ng-click="changeOption('Separated link')">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
  $scope.selected = null;
  $scope.changeOption = function(text) {
    $scope.selected = text;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("ctrl" , function($scope){
  $scope.row = "";
  $scope.items = ['All','Exclusions','Differences','Variable Differences'];
 
  $scope.selectRow = function(item){
      $scope.row = item;
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="filter-requests btn-group">
    <div data-toggle="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
      {{row}}
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
       <li ng-repeat="item in items"  ng-click="selectRow(item)">
           <a href="">{{item}}</a>
        </li>              
     </ul>        
</div>
```